# Why does Data::Dumper show values that link to other values?

Tags: perl, hash

using Data Dumper after parsing some JSON data, I got something like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
   param1 => 'foo',
   param2 => $VAR1->{param1}
};
```

Do I get it right, that param2 is a linked to param1 value?

What is this called? Dynamic hash?

Thanks in Advance, Steve

Comment: It's called `reference`. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_references.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to be confused, the value of param2 is simply a reference that was encountered before in the structure, so Data::Dumper by default shows it as the reference it is. You can set `$Data::Dumper::Deepcopy = 1;` and have Data::Dumper print the actual values instead if you need it for something.
E.g.

```
my $foo = 'foo';

my $test = {
   param1 => \$foo,
   param2 => \$foo
};

print Dumper($test);
```

will print out

```
$VAR1 = {
          'param2' => \'foo',
          'param1' => $VAR1->{'param2'}
        };
```

But if you start with something like:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Deepcopy = 1;
```

Your output will be:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'param1' => \'foo',
          'param2' => \'foo'
        };
```

The default behavior is more useful for visual inspection.

Comment: Neither of these are references; it's a constant string, and so Perl reuses the constant string. This optimization is normally invisible since you can't change a constant string.

Comment: They are references to strings. The '\' in front... Perl doesn't "reuse the constant string", I am not even sure what you mean by that.

Comment: It doesn't seem Data::Dumper does this for constant strings - it's more likely the OP is incorrectly written.

Comment: Re "*The default behavior is more useful for visual inspection.*", The default output is usually harder to read. However, the default output more accurately represents the data structure, and it more accurately recreates the data structure if `eval`ed.

Comment: @Grinnz ah, you were talking about the OP. I switched the example to use references as I assumed the OP messed up the example a bit - as what he posted can't actually happen.